# split in groups by last 4 characters and show that groups

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a column `lastname` varchar(50) in the `mytable` table.

I would to split `lastname` column on groups by **last** 4 letters and count that groups.

What's the way to do that?

Just added:
Is this correct?

```
select substr(lastname,-4) as alpha, count(lastname)
  from mytable
 group by substr(lastname,-4)
```

New Update:

```
select right(lastname,4) as alpha, count(lastname) as total
  from orig
 group by alpha
 order by total desc;
```

Comment: Where is your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: I've just shared it above. Still testing if it is correct. Thank you for pushing me do it on my own - I thought I had no chance to make it for less than an hour.

Comment: The `RIGHT` is more suitable for your case.

Comment: Updated. Is it good enough now or may be even better? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if MySQL supports this non-standard use of column aliases in the group by:

```
select right(lastname,4) as alpha,
       count(lastname) as total
from orig
group by alpha
order by total desc;
```

Or, perhaps:

```
select alpha, count(*) as total
from (select right(lastname,4) as alpha from orig)
group by alpha
order by total desc;
```